# Can Kafka Streams read the data from s3 and send them to other destination such as mysql or olap?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There are little articles about kafka streams which reads the data from s3 and send them to other destination such as olap or oltp.

I cannot see the example code of them so am I correct that kafka streams cannot read s3 and then send them to database systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams must read from a Kafka topic.

There is an S3 Source Kafka Connect *plugin* to get data into a Kafka topic, which you can *then* use Kafka Streams to consume

Similarly, you should use Kafka Connect Sink plugins to write to a database. Kafka Streams is not designed to be used that way.